# How to create an instance from classes that have a common base class?

Tags: swift

Previously I wrote a method in Objective-C like this:

```
Class className = classMap[nameKey];
return [[className alloc] init];
```

Now I need a swift version. I have a dictionary like this:

```
private var classMap = [String: BaseClass.Type]()
classMap[name1] = SomeClass1.self
classMap[name2] = SomeClass2.self
...
```

All the "SomeClass" are subclasses of BaseClass. And this is how I want to use it:

```
func createInstance(from name: String) -> BaseClass? {
    guard let className = modelMap[name] else {
        return nil
    }
    let model = modelClass.init()
    return model
}
```

Then I got an error:

> Constructing an object of class type 'BaseClass' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer

Comment: And why do you think you need to do that? Seriously, while I loved Objective C's dynamism and introspection, Swift taught me that I didn't actually need them. What's the real problem you think that dictionary was solving? It sounds to me like a simple Self factory method might do here but I'd need more info in order to say for sure. Above all, don't use metatypes; Swift hates them.

Comment: @matt I just solved this problem by adding a 'required' keyword before BaseClass.init() method. But if a self factory method is better, I'm happy to use it. Do you mean: if name == "Name1" return Class1() else if name == "Name2" return Class2()... something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by just adding a 'required' keyword:

```
required override init()
```

Is there any better solution? @matt just said a factory method would be better. Does that mean I should write something like:

```
if name == "type_1"
    return Class1()
else if name == "type_2"
    return Class2()
else if ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What I'm suggesting is that you write a factory method that returns `Self`. Consider this model:

```
class Dog {
    required init() {
    }
    class func make() -> Self { // *
        return Self()
    }
}
class NoisyDog : Dog {
}
```

Now `Dog.make()` makes a Dog, typed as a Dog, and `NoisyDog.make()` makes a NoisyDog, typed as a NoisyDog. The nice things about this approach are that the returned instances are automatically typed correctly, and that you can add parameters and property initializations if this thing has properties that need initializing.

Also, though, I'd like to repeat what I said in a comment: Don't pass metatypes around. Your entire

```
classMap[name1] = SomeClass1.self
```

is repugnant to the spirit of Swift. You can pass *function references* around (and I do that absolutely all the time), or even entire *anonymous functions*, where you just use the dictionary to pick the one to call and simply call it; but it sounds to me like you've got some problem and you're still trying to solve it in the Objective-C way even though you're now using Swift, and that's wrong.